# Can't map network drive to FTP server in local VM

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, ftp, vmware-workstation

I've just set up an instance of Ubuntu Server 17.04 running in VMware Workstation 12 Player on my Windows 10 Home workstation.  I got the server configured to my liking (including vsftpd as an FTP server, so that I can map a drive from the host) without any trouble.

Unfortunately, however, when I use the Map Network Drive wizard to connect to "ftp://192.168.154.128" (both with and without a trailing slash), I get an error — 0x80070043 — saying the "network name" cannot be found.

[image]

Running the troubleshooter by clicking Diagnose doesn't turn up anything, simply saying that the troubleshooter failed.

If I try to connect to the same address using the command-line FTP client, however, everything seems to work fine:

```
C:\Users\benblank>ftp 192.168.154.128
Connected to 192.168.154.128.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
User (192.168.154.128:(none)): benblank
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> pwd
257 "/home/benblank" is the current directory
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

Web searches for the error code haven't been very enlightening, primarily suggesting DNS or SMB problems, neither of which are involved, here.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: To be clear: when you used the Map Network Drive wizard, you selected the "Connect to a Web site..." link that launched the "Add Network Location" wizard, and *that's* where you entered the `ftp://...` address, right?

Comment: @jamesdlin — I did not!  I was typing it into the "Folder" box in the Map Network Drive wizard itself.  I have the Network Location set up now, but I still don't seem to be able to access it as a drive.